# Question about the parallel axis theorem

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rigid-body-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

I've a question about the [parallel axis theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_axis_theorem). So I'm perfectly OK with the derivation of the proof in 2D. However in the typical derivation they just say this in my textbook "Because the Zi coordinates are not taken into account into this calculation, we can generalise the summations to include all particles for all slices"

How is this possible? I don't get it how you can generalise for all slices! Please help me, and thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

As you can guess, when something is rotating around the axis, it does not matter much where the particles are in the direction og the axis as much as it matters where they are in the plane perpendicular to the axis,

So let's take some plane perpendicular to the axis and chop an object in half. Then insert more and more planes until we get $n$ more or less planar slices to which you can safely apply planar derivation. Obviously, then you just add up all the equations for different slices. As each of them has $m_ir^2$, the final result for the whole object will have $mr^2$.

In terms of integration (the proof like the one you can find in the wiki article you linked), it just means that nothing concerning the change of moment of inertia depends on $z$, so you can just integrate for $x$ and $y$ (the unit if volume then is a thin line in the body parallel to the axis of rotation).

Comment: But I thought it only makes sense to take a slice where the center of mass is. And then you take advantage of that to make the CM the origin of your coordinate system. Otherwise some of the terms in the proof don't cancel off, right?





Is there any mathematical concept I can read up about that would make this all clear for me?

Comment: The thing is, the _original_ moment of inertia was calculated in this slice using the distance from that old axis through the center of mass (even if the slice's individual center of mass is not on that axis). So when you add them back, they sum up to the original moment of inertia. Probably, you should just read something on integration. In our university it was in the second semester (the first semester covered the basics of calculus, without integrating over several variables, a contour, a surface or inside a volume).